# Linq Order by Icollection Navigation property

Tags: c#, linq, sql-order-by

I have two table which are `items` and `menugroupitemsorder`.
My api gets items by sending page and pagesize. The problem is that items order is correct. When I order by order number from `menugroupitemsorder` table I got an error which is `DbSortClause` expressions must have a type that is order comparable.

Here is my Items Class,

```cs
public class Items
{
   public Guid Id {get;set;}
   public Guid Name {get;set;}
   public virtual List<MenuGroupItemsOrder> MenuGroupItemsOrders{ get; set; } = new List<MenuGroupItemsOrder>();
   ...
}

public class MenuGroupItemsOrder
{
   public Guid MenuGroupId {get;set;}
   public Guid ItemId {get;set;}
   public int OrderNumber {get;set;}
   public virtual Items Items{ get; set; }
   ...
}
```

`MenuGroupItemsOrder` table can be empty.

- If it's empty I use `DefaultIfEmpty()`.
- If it isn't empty I order my items based on `OrderNumber` field from
  `MenuGroupItemsOrder` table.

Here is my Code:

```cs
var itemQuery= _itemRepository.GetQueryable(x => x.IsActive);
itemQuery = itemQuery
      .Include(x => x.MenuGroupItemsOrder)
      .OrderBy(m => m.MenuGroupPosItemPairs.Select(r => r.OrderNumber)
      .FirstOrDefault());
```

Here is my exception:

> System.ArgumentException: DbSortClause expressions must have a type that is order comparable.
> Parameter name: key
> at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.CommandTrees.ExpressionBuilder.Internal.ArgumentValidation.ValidateSortClause(DbExpression key)
> at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.CommandTrees.ExpressionBuilder.DbExpressionBuilder.ToSortClause(DbExpression key)
> at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.OrderByTranslatorBase.TranslateOneLambda(ExpressionConverter parent, DbExpressionBinding sourceBinding, DbExpression lambda)
> at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.OneLambdaTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call, DbExpression& source, DbExpressionBinding& sourceBinding, DbExpression& lambda)
> at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.OneLambdaTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call

Comment: Do you use Entity Framework 6?

Comment: This make no sense to order by included entities. Can you show the expected SQL?